# Как найти медленные тесты PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

Тесты выполняются очень долго. Например, есть итог работы PHPUnit:

```
Time: 669.95 seconds, Memory: 34.00MB

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 4990, Assertions: 18999, Skipped: 218.
```

Как можно узнать, куда ушло время? Какие тесты самые долгие?

Можно ли такую информацию получить без установки и использования посторонних утилит? Идеально, чтобы информация о длинных тестах показывалась прямо после или во время выполнения тестов, еще лучше чтобы данные были доступны программно. Чем проще - тем лучше.

В ключах для запуска PHPUnit ничего похожего нет.

Comment: подключить [allure](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2), посмотреть диаграмму

Comment: Из документации на эту программу не очевидно, какую именно диаграмму смотреть. Может она выводить такую информацию сразу после запуска теста? А после CI может писать в лог данных о долгих тестов?

Comment: нет, она просто генерирует HTML-отчет, в который выводится в том числе таймлайн выполнения

Comment: phpunit -vvv покажет более подробно, чем он занимается в конкретный момент. Возможно, будет сразу видно, что тормозит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант, [предложенный Сергеем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/762982/201364), близок к идеальному, только лишь показывает все-все тесты. А нужно бы увидеть только медленные.

Впрочем, это легко исправить:

```
class MyTestListener extends PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener
{
    private $longTests = [];

    public function endTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $time)
    {
        if ($time > 0.1) {
            $this->longTests[join('::', [get_class($test), $test->getName()])] = $time;
        }
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        foreach ($this->longTests as $testName => $time) {
            $time = round($time, 2);
            echo "Тест '$testName' выполнялся $time секунды\n";
        }
    }
}
```

С таким классом после всех тестов выйдет отчёт о всех тестах, которые заняли больше двух десятых секунды.

В более новых версиях PHPUnit наследовать нужно от `PHPUnit\Framework\BaseTestListener`.

В `phpunit.xml` соответственно появляется секция:

```
<listeners>
    <listener class="MyTestListener">
    </listener>
</listeners>
```

Answer (score 1):

В документации к `phpunit` можно найти сразу два штатных варианта на выбор:

### [XML лог](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/logging.html#logging.xml)

Включенное логирование, например, опцией `--log-junit log.xml` запишет в XML лог в том числе время выполнения каждого теста. Структура документа простая, добавить любую дальнейшую обработку проблемой быть не должно. Пример лога из документации:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="ArrayTest"
             file="/home/sb/ArrayTest.php"
             tests="2"
             assertions="2"
             failures="0"
             errors="0"
             time="0.016030">
    <testcase name="testNewArrayIsEmpty"
              class="ArrayTest"
              file="/home/sb/ArrayTest.php"
              line="6"
              assertions="1"
              time="0.008044"/>
    <testcase name="testArrayContainsAnElement"
              class="ArrayTest"
              file="/home/sb/ArrayTest.php"
              line="15"
              assertions="1"
              time="0.007986"/>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Атрибут `time` - время выполнения в секундах.

Кстати, проверьте, может ваш `CI` вообще этот лог сам понимать умеет, либо понимает рядом лежащие форматы `--log-teamcity` или `--testdox-xml` - там время выполнения есть тоже.

### [Добавить listener на события](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html)

События `startTest` и `endTest` вполне себе предоставляются. В общем-то даже одного `endTest` достаточно, ему вторым параметром время выполнения теста передаётся уже в готовом виде.

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\BaseTestListener;

class SimpleTestListener extends BaseTestListener
{
    public function endTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $time)
    {
        echo 'Test ', $test->getName(), ' completed in ', $time, ' sec', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

И зарегистрировать его в конфиге `phpunit`:

```
<phpunit
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/6.3/phpunit.xsd">
  <listeners>
    <listener class="SimpleTestListener" file="/some/path/to/SimpleTestListener.php">
    </listener>
  </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

Осталось только решить, что и куда из этого `listener`'а выводить. Больше возможностей делать что угодно, но добавить после вызова `phpunit` маленькую программку чтения xml вероятно будет быстрее и проще.

Comment: Как раз последним вариантом я пользуюсь. У вас точно классы в ответе не перепутаны?

Comment: какой с каким классы? Вроде работает локально, время пишет.

Comment: `PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener` и `PHPUnit\Framework\BaseTestListener`

Comment: Фактически это одно и то же, ForwardCompatibility класс-заглушка, но да, лучше на psr4 вариант заменю.

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю использовать [Allure Framework](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2) - специальный фреймворк для генерации отчетов о прохождении тестов, который работает "из коробки", и в котором уже собрано 90%+ необходимого функционала для, собственно, построения отчетов о тестировании (включая категоризацию тестов, их приоритет, указание связанных с тестом багов в таск-трекере, произвольные вложения, логирование отдельных шагов и прочее), включая простые графики о времени выполнения тестов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и информацию отдельно о каждом тесте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Allure создан специально для решения проблем такого характера, поэтому я просто не вижу смысла разрабатывать какое-то свое решение.

Для генерации такого отчета достаточно выполнить три шага:

- Установить и подключить [allure-framework/allure-phpunit](https://83-104381100-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/tmp/workspace/tests/Report/Allure/index.html#suites/788a94bde0df9132a76c9447d1de65d3/b2b92f53f4593769/)
- Прогнать тесты, в ходе которых адаптер Allure будет собирать информацию о выполняемых тестах. В результате выполнения будут собраны метаданные о выполнении тестов (включая время выполнения и всё вышеописанное)
- Скачать и натравить [allure-cli](https://83-104381100-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/tmp/workspace/tests/Report/Allure/index.html#suites/788a94bde0df9132a76c9447d1de65d3/b2b92f53f4593769/) на директорию с метаданными:

  ```
  # создать отчет в директории Allure по результатам, хранящимся в директории allure-results
  allure generate -o Allure allure-results
  ```

Результатом будет набор файлов с приложением, заключенным в index.html. Для открытия потребуется произвольный сервер (Allure требует выполнения AJAX-запросов, которые браузер обычно запрещает для файлов), который уже включен в allure-cli:

```
allure open Allure --port 3333
```

После этого можно будет посмотреть результат по адресу http://localhost:3333